# For every 10 records print something using Symfony2 and Twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm building a page where member addresses are printed to a sheet of labels, and once a sheet is full with 14 addresses on a page, I then want to put a page break after it so that the addresses can be printed on multiple sheets of paper.

How can I achieve this using Twig?

This is my current Twig code:

```
{% for row in data %}
    <div class="label-page">
        <div class="label-section L7163">
            <p>{{row.FirstName}} {{row.Surname}}</p>
            <p>{{row.AddressLine1}}</p>
            {% if row.AddressLine2 != NULL or row.AddressLine2 != '' %}
                <p>{{row.AddressLine2}}</p>
            {% endif %}
            {% if row.Town != NULL or row.Town != '' %}
                <p>{{row.Town}}</p>
            {% endif %}
            {% if row.County != NULL or row.County != '' %}
                <p>{{row.County}}</p>
            {% endif %}
            {% if row.Postcode != NULL or row.Postcode != '' %}
                <p>{{row.Postcode}}</p>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**loop.index**](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html) in your twig loop which returns the current iteration of the loop and [**divisible by(num)**](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tests/divisibleby.html)

```
{% for row in data %}

{% if loop.index is divisible by(10) %}
 /*your page break*/
{% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This works! However you have a typo in your answer. It's `divisibleby(10)` not `divisible by(10)`

Comment: @mickburkejnr are you sure its a typo i guess the official docs also have space after divisible